# Keep element aligned to background

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to create a layout where the paragraph tag should always be aligned to a specific part of the background image.

Link with working example https://codepen.io/marcelcruz/pen/BRgaVL

I want the text to be always inside the crystal ball, but once I resize the window the background shrinks, the crystal ball goes up and they're not aligned anymore.

Is there a way of making the background only shrink on both sides, but not on the top and bottom? Some other better approach for this?

This part of the code looks something like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d5/b0/57/d5b057f0816424bf45ab7d7a72deec5a.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

#text {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 900px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

    <p id="text">TEXT COMES HERE</p>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to add the text to the image

Comment: There is no complete way to do this. When you resize, the ball on image is not center forever. So there is no way to do. Need to specify bound.

Comment: Can't add the text to the image because it's dynamic, generated by JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d5/b0/57/d5b057f0816424bf45ab7d7a72deec5a.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#text {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">

  <p id="text">TEXT COMES HERE</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works, when You set background-size: 100% 100%;

What more? Click [link_for_more](http://www.kurshtml.edu.pl/css/rozmiary,tlo.html)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with an `<img>` tag and relative positioning, example

```css
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.positioning {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="positioning">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d5/b0/57/d5b057f0816424bf45ab7d7a72deec5a.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!